# No file generated on writing file

Tags: android, file, kotlin

Directory has been created but no file and neither toast or log.
Testing directly trough USB.
I search on all FS and no files that match

```kotlin
        val es = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Notes")
        var success = true

        if (!es.exists())
            success = es.mkdir()

        if (success) {
            val sd = File(note.noteTitle + "-" + note.timeStamp)

            if (!sd.exists())
                success = sd.mkdir()

            if (success) {
                val dest = File(sd, note.noteTitle)

                PrintWriter(dest).use { out -> out.println(note.noteDescription) }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "directory not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Comment: You do not have the rights to create files or directories in the root of external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare i had allowed external storage permission `checkPermission(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
        )` i made a function to check if permission is granted with a toast and it returned granted
    }`

Comment: That does not matter. You do not have read/write access to everything on external storage with that permission on Android 11 and higher. In particular, you do not have the rights to create files or directories in the root of external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare my android version is 8.1